# Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting fi)

Tags: shell, sh

I am writing a backup script.
I think my syntax is correct but it still gives me an error.

Here's my script:

```sh
if [ ! -f $LIST ]; then
    /usr/bin/tar -g $FULLLIST -zpcf $FULL $TGT
    cp $FULLLIST $DIFFLIST
    expect << EOF
    spawn /usr/bin/scp $FULL $HOST:$DST
    expect "password:"
    send "blahblah\r"
    expect eof
    EOF
    rm $FULL
elif [ $DAY == 01 ]; then
    *same as above*
elif [ $DAYOFWEEK == 0 ]; then
    *same as above*
else
    *same as above*
fi
```

The error is

```
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

When I type in "./webbackup.sh"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You incorrectly closed here document. When youw rite:

```
expect <<EOF
```

The line has to be **exactly** `EOF`. **No spaces before and after it**. Exactly `EOF`. You want:

```
    expect << EOF
    spawn ...
^^^^ - these spaces are "preserved"
EOF
   ^ also no spaces after!
```

You can use `-<delimiter>` and then it will ignore leading tabs. **Not spaces**.

```
    expect <<-EOF
    spawn /usr/bin/scp $FULL $HOST:$DST
    ...
    EOF
^^^^ - this is a tab character
```

Research a *here-document* in shell.

Comment: I intended to use multiple expect.